# automatically resizing the jpanel

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, null-layout-manager

Is there anyway of getting JPanel resized (vertically) automatically as the components are added?  I have assigned the layout manager to null.

Comment: *"Is there anyway of getting JPanel resized (vertically) automatically as the components are added?"* Sure, the first step is.. *"I have assigned the layout manager to null."* ..use an appropriate layout manager.

Comment: How are you designing your JPanel? Are you using the straight Swing code and a command-line compiler or are you using a GUI Builder in NetBeans or Eclipse?

Comment: I am using Netbeans.  But, some components are to be added dynamically depending on other values.

Comment: See the [nested layout example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) - the labels 1 through 25 are dynamically added.

Comment: *"depending on other values."*  Can you vague that up for me?  What is the logic behind the positioning?  Is it a seating plan? A schematic? A family tree?  What..?

Comment: I think that you are hampering your program's abilities by using null layout. As many of the experienced Swing programers are telling you -- learn about and use the layout managers. Then this problem often becomes trivial.

Answer (score 5):

Concider using the fitting layout manager that will help you expand the way you want to when you add the components

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html

I think you are looking for the GridLayout and possibly use FlowLayout JPanels inside so that they dont expand, but this will depend on what you want to insert.